# Write to space separated 2 column text without specifying delimiter in c++

Tags: c++, file, file-handling, ofstream, c++98

I am using **C++ 98**. Here is my code. It is getting the text from a `lineEdit` of a Qt4 form.

```cpp
strcpy(Name,ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::fromStdString(Name)) );
strcpy(Class,ui->lineEdit_1->setText(QString::fromStdString(Class)));
strcpy(Grade,ui->lineEdit_2->setText(QString::fromStdString(Grade)));

std::ofstream myfile;
myfile.open(mypath,std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out );
myfile<<Name<<"\t"<<"Name"<<"\n";
myfile<<Class<<"\t"<<"Class"<<"\n";
myfile<<Grade<<"\t"<<"Grade"<<"\n";
```

Here is 2 column space separated  text file  `sample.conf`:

```
AA.    Name
BB     Class
CC     Grade
```

It is updating the file **correctly**

My question is there any way to write above text file in without using **delimiter** like in the above case is **\t** .

By using other datatype in like **FILE** or **ofstream** or **some other** that don't use **delimiter(\t)** for **writing** file ?

**That can directly write to file column**

Note:
My purpose is not restrict file **writing** to it's  delimiter(tab,space,.etc)

Comment: You could put two spaces instead with "  " but I suspect you are asking for a reason, and want something more general.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write directly into columns, but you can format your output with IO manipulators:

```
#include <iomanip>
...
std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::left << "Column 1"
          << std::setw(10) << std::left << "Column 2"
          << '\n';
```

**But beware:** `std::setw` does not truncate any data. If the texts are longer, the column in this row will be longer than specified.